# Search for a string from another database and remove the rows if string found

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes with different number of rows. here are the tails of dataframes:

[image]

I want to remove the rows from df2 which don't contain the part of superstring COMPANY from df1. (df1 COMPANY strings are longer than df2 COMPANY strings).

Can anyone help?
thanks in advance

Comment: what do you mean by *problem is company names are longer in df1 mostly than in df2.* the strings doesn't match exactly? can you give example

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate on each row of `df2` and drop it in case the company name can't be found in df1 "company" column, like this:

```py
for index, row in df2.iterrows():
    if row["COMPANY"] not in df1["COMPANY"].values:
        df2.drop([index], inplace=True)
```